# Why MySQL Container Keeps Restarting on Windows 10 Home with WSL 2?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a Laravel development environment on my local machine, but my MySQL container keeps on restarting.

Using: Windows 10 Home with WSL2 and Docker Desktop

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
    laravel:

services:

    web:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        depends_on:
            - phpfpm
            - db
        networks:
            - laravel


    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        networks:
            - laravel


    phpfpm:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: phpfpm
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel


    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin:5-fpm-alpine
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        networks:
            - laravel
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

**Nginx (default.conf)**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/laravelapp/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/935096/docker-nginx-php-fpm-error-emerg-11-host-not-found-in-upstream
        resolver 127.0.0.11; # docker's internal fixed IP address
        set $upstream phpfpm:9000;
        # nginx will now start if host is not reachable
        fastcgi_pass $upstream; 
        # Source End
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

`docker-compose ps` or `docker deskop` shows that `mysql` container status as `restarting`.

It restarts once in a while, but stops again. It seems like something is terribly wrong when I look at the log file, but I couldn't make sense.

**`mysql` container log**

```
2020-11-07 17:09:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.

2020-11-07 17:09:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2020-11-07 17:09:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.

2020-11-07T17:09:28.627271Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 1

2020-11-07T17:09:28.634780Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive

2020-11-07T17:09:28.654292Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2020-11-07T17:09:30.967703Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist

2020-11-07T17:09:31.108803Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.187838Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock

2020-11-07T17:09:31.251299Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.304178Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.305509Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.306123Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 00514c52-211c-11eb-bbbd-0242ac170002.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.415490Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.439838Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.440013Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key

2020-11-07T17:09:31.444031Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.445904Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.520973Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.521733Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2020-11-07T17:09:31.522162Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist

2020-11-07T17:09:31.522393Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.523156Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

2020-11-07T17:09:31.523377Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.

2020-11-07T17:09:31.523987Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2020-11-07T17:09:32.995214Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22) MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Interesting! I tried using managed volumes and mysql didn't crash. Now `db` service has following `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` and `volumes:` has `- db_data:/var/lib/mysql` with volumes defined at bottom. However, connection is refused now. `docker-compose exec db mysql -u root -p` gives me `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. Any idea anyone?

Comment: I am guessing that my previous mapping had some windows/linux filesystem compatibility issue with docker. I tried to persist the mysql database on my project folder (windows file systems mapped from WSL 2 by docker). Using managed volume solved that problem I think

Answer (score 5):

Instead of mapped volumes for data persistence, I used the managed volume and it is not crashing anymore

**Previous**

```
db:
        image: mysql:8.0.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        networks:
            - laravel
```

**Now**

```
db:
        image: mysql:8.0.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        networks:
            - laravel

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked nice. but we need an explanation more about the issue. may other can help us on what really the problem. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I posted that question when I was starting with docker... After some research, I found out that the main culprit is that the different Linux distro used different user id for the same user name. So basically the permissions problem.

Please read this article if that makes sense to you... https://medium.com/swlh/wordpress-deployment-with-nginx-php-fpm-and-mariadb-using-docker-compose-55f59e5c1a

I have to remove the current user from ubuntu and add the user that matches the alpine user. That's the distro I was using at that time.

Probably that's the gotcha I think... if you are using ubuntu and using docker image of alpine Linux... then the user name and user id may vary...

The article I have referenced shows how to remove users from your current Linux distro and add the same user with a different user id.